# keeping posted image through multiple pages

Tags: php, file

I am using a multi-page form user sign-up process. The values from the forms on each page are saved in `$_SESSION['temp']` and then on the last page (assuming there are no errors), the information is then saved in the database and the profile picture that was uploaded on the first page will be saved in a new folder on the server.

Since the image is uploaded on the first page (`$_FILES["pic"]`) I don't want it to expire before getting to the last page. I'm assuming the `$_FILES` superglobal expires after the script is run? If so, what's the simplest way to carry it through to the last page?

Comment: I assume you mean `$_SESSION['temp'][$pageNo]` otherwise you overwrite the information from the previous pages? You will have to save the 'image information' somewhere 'semi permanent'. i.e. a 'staging area'' that gets 'cleaned up' regularly. You move the image from the 'staging area' if all is ok?

Comment: assign a session variable to the file, then you can carry it out later for other pages using sessions. Remember to use `isset()` throughout the entire sessions.

Comment: The $_SESSION['temp'] is an array

Comment: it's guesswork right now and answers given may be in for a long haul. Post your code

Comment: I suspect you are 'overthinking' the problem. Imagine you allowed 30 minutes for someone to complete the registration process? Anything in the 'staging area' that is more 30 minutes old can be deleted. Your 'registration routine' checks the 'staging area' for valid information. If it doesn't find it the registration fails.

Answer (score 0):

Hiw about create tmp table store it there and delete it if error or store to permant table, and for the image store it in tmp folder. Just like the data delete on error move on success. Hope it help

Comment: The problem is that if they change windows or leave without hitting "cancel" or without completing it will just stay on the server taking up space. I could use a CRON job to periodically clear it, but I don't want to clear up any that are still in use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a session equal to the file?

```
$_SESSION["pic"] = $_FILES["pic"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Re post the firs post as hidden field on 2nd post and repost 1st 2nd as hidden field and 3rd post and soon.

Comment: I was thinking something similar. Not sure exactly what that code would look like.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy you have chosen is rather wrong and will only give you headache, you can already see your question being down-voted. You should better proceed with the file upload only after the user has completed the registration. This way you don't have to worry about storing data that is never going to be used due to some events between the time of the upload and finishing the registration.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what I did was go ahead and save the picture on the server. But after one day it will be deleted if they don't complete the registration process.